# ajax-datatables-rails how to use view_columns with one class associated twice

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datatables

I use this gem for datatables in rails and have problem working with one Model associated twice

https://github.com/jbox-web/ajax-datatables-rails

this is my model

```
class Associate < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :missions
    has_many :coordinator_missions, :class_name => "Mission", :foreign_key  => "coordinator_id"
end
class Mission < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :associate
  belongs_to :coordinator, :class_name => "Associate"
end
```

Showing data in table works fine, but I cannot search because of Coordinator
this is my datatable code

```
class MissionDatatable < AjaxDatatablesRails::Base


  def view_columns
    @view_columns ||= {
       id: { source: "Mission.id", cond: :eq },
       fy: {source: "Mission.fy"},
       associate_email: {source: "Associate.email"},
       associate_id: {source: "Mission.associate_id"},
       coordinator_email: { source: "Coordinator.email" },
       coordinator_id: { source: "Mission.coordinator_id" },
       name: { source: "Mission.name" },
       fye_output: { source: "Mission.fye_output" },
       status: { source: "Mission.status" },
       created_at: { source: "Mission.created_at" },
       updated_at: { source: "Mission.updated_at" }
    }
  end



  def data
    records.map do |mission|
      {
        # example:
         id: mission.id,
         fy: mission.fy,
         associate_email: mission.associate.email,
         associate_id: mission.associate_id,
         coordinator_email: mission.coordinator.email,
         coordinator_id: mission.coordinator_id,
         name: mission.name,
         fye_output: mission.fye_output,
         status: mission.status,
         created_at: mission.created_at,
         updated_at: mission.updated_at
        }
    end
  end

  private



def get_raw_records
  Mission.joins(:associate).joins(:coordinator)
end


end
```

could you pls help me how to do correct setup for one model associated twice?
The error in log is "wrong constant name Coordinator"

edit: added log

```
> Started GET
> "/missions.json?draw=3&columns%5B0%5D%5Bdata%5D=fy&columns%5B0%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B0%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B0%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B0%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B0%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B1%5D%5Bdata%5D=associate_email&columns%5B1%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B1%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B1%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B1%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B1%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B2%5D%5Bdata%5D=guild_name&columns%5B2%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B2%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B2%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B2%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B2%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B3%5D%5Bdata%5D=coordinator_email&columns%5B3%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B3%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B3%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B3%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B3%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B4%5D%5Bdata%5D=name&columns%5B4%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B4%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B4%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B4%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B4%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B5%5D%5Bdata%5D=eighty&columns%5B5%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B5%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B5%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B5%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B5%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B6%5D%5Bdata%5D=q1_output&columns%5B6%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B6%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B6%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B6%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B6%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B7%5D%5Bdata%5D=q1_status&columns%5B7%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B7%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B7%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B7%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B7%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B8%5D%5Bdata%5D=q2_output&columns%5B8%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B8%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B8%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B8%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B8%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B9%5D%5Bdata%5D=q2_status&columns%5B9%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B9%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B9%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B9%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B9%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B10%5D%5Bdata%5D=q3_output&columns%5B10%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B10%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B10%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B10%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B10%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B11%5D%5Bdata%5D=q3_status&columns%5B11%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B11%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B11%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B11%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B11%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B12%5D%5Bdata%5D=fye_output&columns%5B12%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B12%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B12%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B12%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B12%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B13%5D%5Bdata%5D=status&columns%5B13%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B13%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B13%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B13%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B13%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B14%5D%5Bdata%5D=created_at&columns%5B14%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B14%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B14%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B14%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B14%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B15%5D%5Bdata%5D=updated_at&columns%5B15%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B15%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B15%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B15%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B15%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B16%5D%5Bdata%5D=no_delete_mission&columns%5B16%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B16%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=false&columns%5B16%5D%5Borderable%5D=false&columns%5B16%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B16%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&order%5B0%5D%5Bcolumn%5D=0&order%5B0%5D%5Bdir%5D=asc&start=0&length=10&search%5Bvalue%5D=bb&search%5Bregex%5D=false&_=1530222117292"
> for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-06-28 22:42:29 +0100 Processing by
> MissionsController#index as JSON   Parameters: {"draw"=>"3",
> "columns"=>{"0"=>{"data"=>"fy", "name"=>"", "searchable"=>"true",
> "orderable"=>"true", "search"=>{"value"=>"", "regex"=>"false"}},
> "1"=>{"data"=>"associate_email", "name"=>"", "searchable"=>"true",
> "orderable"=>"true", "search"=>{"value"=>"", "regex"=>"false"}},
> "2"=>{"data"=>"guild_name", "name"=>"", "searchable"=>"true",
> "orderable"=>"true", "search"=>{"value"=>"", "regex"=>"false"}},
> "3"=>{"data"=>"coordinator_email", "name"=>"", "searchable"=>"true",
> "orderable"=>"true", "search"=>{"value"=>"", "regex"=>"false"}},
> "4"=>{"data"=>"name", "name"=>"", "searchable"=>"true",
> "orderable"=>"true", "search"=>{"value"=>"", "regex"=>"false"}},
> "5"=>{"data"=>"eighty", "name"=>"", "searchable"=>"true",
> "orderable"=>"true", "search"=>{"value"=>"", "regex"=>"false"}},
> "6"=>{"data"=>"q1_output", "name"=>"", "searchable"=>"true",
> "orderable"=>"true", "search"=>{"value"=>"", "regex"=>"false"}},
> "7"=>{"data"=>"q1_status", "name"=>"", "searchable"=>"true",
> "orderable"=>"true", "search"=>{"value"=>"", "regex"=>"false"}},
> "8"=>{"data"=>"q2_output", "name"=>"", "searchable"=>"true",
> "orderable"=>"true", "search"=>{"value"=>"", "regex"=>"false"}},
> "9"=>{"data"=>"q2_status", "name"=>"", "searchable"=>"true",
> "orderable"=>"true", "search"=>{"value"=>"", "regex"=>"false"}},
> "10"=>{"data"=>"q3_output", "name"=>"", "searchable"=>"true",
> "orderable"=>"true", "search"=>{"value"=>"", "regex"=>"false"}},
> "11"=>{"data"=>"q3_status", "name"=>"", "searchable"=>"true",
> "orderable"=>"true", "search"=>{"value"=>"", "regex"=>"false"}},
> "12"=>{"data"=>"fye_output", "name"=>"", "searchable"=>"true",
> "orderable"=>"true", "search"=>{"value"=>"", "regex"=>"false"}},
> "13"=>{"data"=>"status", "name"=>"", "searchable"=>"true",
> "orderable"=>"true", "search"=>{"value"=>"", "regex"=>"false"}},
> "14"=>{"data"=>"created_at", "name"=>"", "searchable"=>"true",
> "orderable"=>"true", "search"=>{"value"=>"", "regex"=>"false"}},
> "15"=>{"data"=>"updated_at", "name"=>"", "searchable"=>"true",
> "orderable"=>"true", "search"=>{"value"=>"", "regex"=>"false"}},
> "16"=>{"data"=>"no_delete_mission", "name"=>"", "searchable"=>"false",
> "orderable"=>"false", "search"=>{"value"=>"", "regex"=>"false"}}},
> "order"=>{"0"=>{"column"=>"0", "dir"=>"asc"}}, "start"=>"0",
> "length"=>"10", "search"=>{"value"=>"bb", "regex"=>"false"},
> "_"=>"1530222117292"}   ActiveRecord::SessionStore::Session Load
> (3.6ms)  SELECT  "sessions".* FROM "sessions" WHERE
> "sessions"."session_id" = $1  ORDER BY "sessions"."id" ASC LIMIT 1 
> [["session_id", "1f1458aac34369eaa4ce2ddcd835c07c"]]   User Load
> (1.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1  ORDER
> BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 58]]   User Load (0.9ms)  SELECT 
> "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 58  ORDER BY "users"."id"
> ASC LIMIT 1    (0.8ms)  SELECT "tribes"."region" FROM "tribes" WHERE
> (region is not null)    (2.3ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "missions" INNER
> JOIN "associates" ON "associates"."id" = "missions"."associate_id"
> INNER JOIN "associates" "coordinators_missions" ON
> "coordinators_missions"."id" = "missions"."coordinator_id" Completed
> 500 Internal Server Error in 32ms (ActiveRecord: 14.2ms)
> 
> NameError (uninitialized constant Coordinator):  
> app/controllers/missions_controller.rb:15:in `block (2 levels) in
> index'   app/controllers/missions_controller.rb:11:in `index'
```

edit2: controller code

```
 def index

     respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.json do
         render json: ::MissionDatatable.new(view_context, {region: get_current_user_region_filter})

      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: Can you add a stacktrace to the bottom of your post? Would help give specific context, thanks!

Comment: there are some more data(columns) which I removed in original question to simplify the problem, but now the log is attached

Comment: Just curious - why do you have two `has_many`'s and two `belongs_to`'s? Is it because you use both `@associate.missions` and `@associate.cooridinator_missions`? and both `@mission.associate` and `@mission.coordinator`?

I think you can do what you want with one line, unless you want both methods available in each class. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#options-for-belongs-to-class-name

Comment: Can you paste your `MissionsController` as well? That's what the stacktrace is complaining about...`app/controllers/missions_controller.rb:11:in `index'`

Comment: Yes, it is because one mission needs to have associate and coordinator, but actually both are just "users" from associate class

Comment: Ok great. Thanks for explanation.

Comment: Can you paste controller code? That's where another error lies.

Comment: added controller code, it is just simple piece

Comment: Please paste your entire missions controller class. Also is this on GitHub or the like?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you don't have a constant named `Coordinator` and according to the [documentation on associated models](https://github.com/jbox-web/ajax-datatables-rails#associated-and-nested-models) you need to use the ActiveRecord class name, `Associate`, not `Coordinator`.

Comment: I use class name Associate for associates, but as I mentioned above I have referenced one class twice (it works in active record, I can get mission.associate and mission.coordinator) but if I use Associate.email in defining data I get email from associate, not coordinator

Comment: But `Coordinator` is not a class. And `.coordinator` is a dynamic method on an instance of the `Mission` class. I believe you're considering it a class when it's not one. I think you want `Associate.email`

Comment: I tried this, if I use Associate.email I get no error but actually in column where is coordinator email it is not searching..so searching works fine but ignores this column with coordinators email

Comment: That's a big step! At least we've got the constant error gone.

Comment: You probably also want to tweak your `get_raw_records` joins query. There is no model/table named `Coordinator`. I don't think that's giving you what you want. I'm pretty sure that's your new question, now that we've solved the first bug. Can you accept this answer, and then we'll figure out the new problem?

Comment: thanks for all your effort but this (changing to Associate.email) I already tried before creating this question, it is not fixing my issue because it is completely ignoring my coordinator data
in the table I have for mission associate_id and coordinator_id and I need to be able to search with datatables also within coordinators which I am not

Comment: Do you use byebug? You should insert a byebug statement and then see what `get_raw_records` is giving you because I don't think you're returning the records you need with `Mission.joins(:associate).joins(:coordinator)`.

Comment: get raw records works fine, when I see data from the table in datatables, all are fine (associates and coordinators are shown OK), only searching is not working

Comment: Ok, sorry, there's a lot in this post and didn't know it was just search. Can you please post your entire MissionsController file? I'm trying to find out exactly what line is trying to call that `Coordinator` class that does not exist...from your stacktrace.

Comment: And is your code on Github so I can try to debug locally?

Comment: it is not in other methods of class Mission...thats the question, I am not sure how to use two associations of one class in this specific gem for searching...and no, it is not on github...but thanks anyway for trying I hope somebody who is familiar with this gem will know

Comment: It's very difficult to debug this without seeing the entire controller class or be in front of it to drop in a byebug and see what all the methods return down the stack. Sorry I've spent a lot of time and asked you for the whole controller, but you're not providing it so it's tough to continue. Maybe I'll just create test app with this gem and use your data models and get it work then let you know. Good luck!